# List date time format

Tags: list

I need a list column to be formatted as short time
I understand all date / time formats are UTC?
My Access DB needs 2 columns to be short time 
Any ideas appreciated?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a calculated column , based on another date & Time column and this calculated column display only the time, you can use the below formula:

```
=TEXT([Date Column],"hh:mm")
```

Comment: Thanks for reply - I have already done this but i need to be able to "update" the fields - sorry perhaps I did not explain properly?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution by changing my Access Table Date/Time by:

Change Date/Time Format to "Number" 
Change Filed Size to "Double"

Export / Import to SharePoint & updates ok!

Hope this helps somebody else!